# Route is n'ont defined if i add new nav link on laravel breeze navigation.blade.php

Tags: routes, hyperlink, navigation, laravel-blade, navbar

I would like to add a new button in the navigation bar from the navigation.blade.php file. But after adding and specifying the existing route in the link, the dashboard trying to load crashes with an error saying that the route is not defined. Is there a specific way to modify the navigation bar generated by laravel breeze?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps anyone.  This gave me a lot of headache.
After a few hours I did this and it worked

1. In the `Web.php` file, don't forget this on top:

   ```
   (use App\Livewire\Component;)

    Route::get('/component', Component::class)->name('Component.index');
   ```
2. In the `navigation.blade.php` file

   ```
   <x-nav-link :href="route('Component.index')" :active="request()->routeIs('Component.index')" wire:navigate>
                       {{ __('order') }}
   ```